# Noetherian topological subspaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove that any subset of a noetherian topological space is noetherian in its induced topology.

**MY ATTEMPT OF SOLUTION**

Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ a subspace of $X$. If $F=\{U_i\cap Y\}$ is a family of open subsets of $Y$, where the $U_i$ are open subsets of $X$, can I say that $M\cap Y$ is a maximal element of $F$, where $M$ is a maximal element of the $U_i$'s? If don't, I don't know how to solve this question.

I really need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that approach does not work so well. It could be that $M$ is maximal among the $U_i$'s, but $M \cap Y$ is not maximal among the $U_i \cap Y$'s.

Instead, prove the following: a space $X$ is Noetherian if and only if every subspace of $X$ is quasi-compact. With this alternative characterization, it is obvious that $Y$ is also Noetherian, since every subspace of $Y$ is also a subspace of $X$.